# Search files with snap

Tags: dpkg, snap

I've started to use snap, but I couldn't find all features I had with dpkg.

1. How to find which snap provides a given file (`dpkg -S`)?
2. How to find which snap will provide a given file (`apt-file search`)?
3. How to find list of files in a given snap (`dpkg -L`)?

Thanks.

Comment: See if this  helps: https://docs.snapcraft.io/core/usage

Comment: I started there. Unfortunately, only useful command if `snap find`, which roughly corresponds to `apt-cache search`. None of asked problems are present in that article.

Comment: +1 here. Without this simple and mature functionality Snap is useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to request this changes by sending bug-reports to LaunchPad:

- [bug 1748627](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1748627) - `snap` should provide functionality to show files, which are included to installed snap (analog of `dpkg -L`);
- [bug 1748628](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1748628) - `snap` should provide functionality to show files, which are included into non-installed snap (analog of `apt-file list`)
- [bug 1748630](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1748630) - snap`should provide functionality to find installed snap which contain known file (analog of`dpkg -S`)
- [bug 1748633](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1748633) - 
  `snap` should provide functionality to find non-installed snap which contain known file (analog of `apt-file search`)

As for today - all releases 14.04 LTS, 16.04 LTS, 17.10 and 18.04 LTS do not have requested functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of this is possible today (and it would need changes on both sides, the store and snapd to support this), but if you re-ask the question on https://forum.snapcraft.io/ in the snapd category, the snapd developers will see and discuss it ...

There is also some work done by the snapcraft team to include manifest files in snaps ( https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/use-a-separate-manifest-file-or-save-everything-in-snap-snapcraft-yaml/1152 and https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/record-machine-information-in-the-manifest/1961 ), perhaps this feature could be extended to include searchable files lists too ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks like snaps is just unfitted for production use, and there are almost no plans to fix this. Desktop may be fine, but why one should use so basic packet manager when there is a dpkg with all nices, whistles and services?